# Install SOAP for PHP 7 in Amazon Linux

Tags: soap, php-7, amazon-linux

Having a hard time finding SOAP extensions for PHP 7.

I've tried `yum install php7.0-soap`, but that results in:

> *No package php7.0-soap available.*

Also tried `yum install php-soap`, that one looks like its specific to PHP 5.3, and it results in:

> *Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64*

Is there a SOAP package specific for PHP 7, Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command is:

```
yum install php70-soap
```

Thank you Brian Woods